# Why I can't calculate the factorial of a non-integer in this way?

Tags: factorial

If I can calculate $6!$ as $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6$; why is incorrect calculate the factorial of $6.1$ as $1.1 \times 2.1 \times 3.1 \times 4.1 \times 5.1 \times 6.1$?

Please note that I'm not asking for the right way to calculate $6.1!$

I'm asking why is incorrect calculate the factorial in this way.

Comment: So you would define $x!$ to be $x(x - 1) \cdots (x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + 1)$ for $x\geq 1$?

Comment: I imagine this results in a function that is not  differentiable at integers. Also, not sure about the functional relation

Comment: You can calculate that way, but you will have a conflict with lots of people using $\Gamma$-function to do that.

Comment: Too bad you would be discarding all the remarkable properties of the more commonly used extension, the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Wasn't obvious, this method does obey the appropriate functional relation; however, lack of derivative at the integers

Comment: The real reason is that the factorial function is only defined for non negative integers. In your example $\,6.1\,$ is not a integer and therefore the value of $\,6.1!\,$ is not defined. Your calculation produces a number which is not the factorial of an integer.

Comment: And why is important that lack of derivative at the integers Will Jagy?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understand your point Gary. Can you explain it to me in another way? Thanks

Comment: Why properties are more important that know if these multiplications give us the true factorials or not Lee Mosher?

Comment: Why isn't the factorial of an integer Somos?

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted, Pablo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$6!=1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times6$ is a product of six numbers, and $7!$ is a product of seven numbers, so logically $(6.1)!$ should be a product of $6.1$ numbers, not a product of six numbers. That's one way to see why it's the wrong way to compute $(6.1)!$.

Defining $(6+r)!$ to be $(1+r)(2+r)\cdots(6+r)$ runs into trouble for $r>1$, e.g., it gives $8!=(6+2)!=(1+2)(2+2)\cdots(6+2)=20160$, which is incorrect.

There are also problems going backwards: should $(5.9)!$ be $.9\times1.9\times\cdots\times5.9$ (since $5.9=6-0.1$), or should it be $1.9\times2.9\times\cdots\times5.9$ (since $5.9=5+0.9$)?

Comment: You are right in your approach Gerry Myerson. But I saw it more as undecision: "Where I should start  computing?" rather than as impossible.

Gamma function took a decision about where to start computing: from 1 + r; being r less than 1.

You could find that if you divide !6.1 by 0.1! (given by Gamma) and see that the number that you obtain is equivalent to 6.1 x 5.1 x 4.1 x 3.1 x 2.1 x 1.1.

If this is incorrect, why Gamma function use this in its calculations?

Comment: OK. I think @Will Jagy has it right; the function you've defined is not differentiable at integer points. The Gamma function is, so what you've defined is not the Gamma function. And given a choice between two ways of extending the domain of a function, if one way gives a differentiable function, and the other doesn't, then the differentiable one is to be preferred, because of how important derivatives are in applications. The graph of your function has "corners" at the integers; the graph of Gamma is smooth.

Comment: Gerry Myerson Thanks to confirm to me that the function isn't differentiable at integer points. I was trying to graph the function n! where n isn't an integer and this is exactly what this found.  And thanks to you because now I understand why you need a differentiable function. Thanks

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" my answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.